# swift navigation and multiple views

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to see if this even correct.  But I have multiple views tied to a single navigation controller

[image]

Ive given an id to the seque from the listing to the navigation controller
mainSeque and from the navigation controller to the login loginViewSeque

But when I try to go to the login view when inside viewDidLoad() using the code:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginViewSegue", sender: self)
```

the app crashes.  So it would seem that its weird either incorrectly or called incorrectly.

I'm assuming on navigation controller can have multiple views?  In this case the login and config view.  Or does each view require its own navigation controller?

Comment: You can have only one `navigation controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay there are some severe mistakes in your program. Now you have made instances of 2 Navigation Controller, where you actually require only 1. Remove the one after the `tableViewController` and create a segue from `tableViewController` to your `loginViewController`. Most probably you would wanna make the segue call when the user presses the 'LOCK' button on the top bar. So just hold control and drag from the lock to `loginViewController`.And you could provide another `UIButton` to access the `configViewController` on your `tableViewController` to segue in the similar manner.That should work for you.

Comment: OK I finally get the relationship of the navigation controller and the views.  Thank you for clearing it up for me